# Eliding a proof when generating HTML using coqdoc

Tags: coq

As one can see in *Software Foundations Books* for example in the [Lists Chapter](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/lf-current/Lists.html) there are some proofs which are elided (search elided in the page) and you can expand them by pushing the `+` button. This book is made using `coqdoc` I assume, so there should be a way to elide some proofs when generating HTML file, which I am unable to find. I want to create a documentation which I prefer to elide some long proofs, and like to know how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [coqdocjs](https://github.com/coq-community/coqdocjs) to make proofs collapsible in the generated HTML.

Software Foundations does it differently, with its own internal scripts to tweak the HTML by substituting some special comments. But the end result is similar.